# converting txt into an array of values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I'm new to React.js (using hooks) and want to learn by simply doing my own projects(coding), my question is I want to fetch data for example from ksngfr.com/something.txt and the data I'm getting from there is '2005-07-09 03:05 1:74539 2:29735 3:95426 4:35489 ...' and it is '.txt', I want to put them into an array like this : [”74539”, ”29735”, ”95426”,”35489”], as you can see i dont want to have this in array '2005-07-09 03:05', i have checked from internet and came up with a solution but getting error messages 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null'. English is not my mother language, sorry for mistakes

data i'm fetching:

[image]

this is what i want to achieve :

[image]

my code:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  var daattaa, k;
  const obj = {};
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let corsAnywhere = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      let something = "http://ksngfr.com/something.txt";
      await fetch(corsAnywhere + something)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => {
          setData(result);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  daattaa = data.split(" ");

  daattaa.forEach((d) => {
    var propertyK = d.split(":")[0];
    var propertyv = d.split(":")[1];
    obj[propertyK] = propertyv;
  });
  k = Object.values(obj);

  console.log(k);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {k.map((content) => (
        <h1>{content}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm:

```
const theDataArr = data.split('\n\r');
const nums = theDataArr.map((cur, index) => {
  if (index === 0)
    return undefined;
  return cur.split(':')[1];
});
```

Comment: getting error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Comment: Try ````\n\t```` for first split

Comment: You mean 2 splits ?, you can put code here, when i accept it , put it as question

Comment: not working should i have 'propertyK','propertyv' ?

Comment: Console log the result of fetched data and theDataArr. No you shouldn't

Comment: You mean :  const theDataArr = data.split("\n\r");
  const nums = theDataArr.map((cur, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return undefined;
    return cur.split(":")[1];
  });

  console.log(nums);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {nums.map((content) => (
        <h1>{content}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226192/discussion-between-walee-and-hadi-ahmadi).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because initially data is set to `null` and while your actual data is being fetched and set in the background,  `daattaa = data.split(" ")` (as null.split(" ")) will get executed. 
 Changing
`daattaa = data.split(" ");` to `daattaa = data ? data.split(" ") : [];` should work.

Also you can use `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`and and set the formatted array from the result too

```
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  let corsAnywhere = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  let something = "http://ksngfr.com/something.txt";
  await fetch(corsAnywhere + something)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => {
      setData(result.split(" "));
    });
  };
 fetchData();
}, []);
```

and then you don't need the `daattaa` variable at all.

Comment: i'm getting now : [undefined, "06↵1"]

Comment: Why undefined and why this '↵' ?

Comment: it's difficult to answer this without seeing what is in `data`.

Comment: the picture i added in my question is example of my data

Comment: can you log the data and paste it here so that I can figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a help of regexp:

```
var input = "2005-07-09 03:05 1:74539 2:29735 3:95426 4:35489";
var arr = input.split(" ");
var regex = /[\w:]+(?=;|$)/;

arr.forEach((text, i) => {
  if (i > 1) {
    var curText = regex.exec(text).toString();
    alert(curText.split(':')[1]);
  }
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-shannon-c3y37?file=/src/index.js